# How to find offsetWidth with a multiline element?

Tags: javascript

I've built a tooltip where I calculate the position for the tooltip from the hovered element's offsetWidth and offsetHeight,  that works great with one exception:  When the element which is to be hovered over runs down onto the next line the elements offsetWidth becomes much larger and therefore sends the tooltip the width length away from the element.

Whats the best way to handle that?  I'd like to avoid repositioning the tooltip to where the mouse is as that wouldn't be as aesthetically appealing and would be a larger re-factor.

Note: Javascript only, no jQuery please.

Comment: How is the width of the element calculated? CSS fixed value?

Comment: Maybe some code or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help. When I computed the offsetWidth for a multi-line element, I still got the same width. So I guess I'm confused.

Comment: I found a solution: The offsetWidth of the text element was the width of the entire line once it became a multi-line element which is strange to me that it was not for sdleihssirhc.

The fix was actually quite simple, I added a display: inline-block to the element and voila!

Note that this may not work in older version of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from my comment above resolved it for me.  Thank you for the suggestions.

I basically added the css element "display: inline-block" to the multi-line element and it worked IE6-9 FF & WEbkit.

Note that IE 5.5-7 may have issues with display: inline-block.